# Как правильно перемешать пятнашки, чтобы их можно было собрать?

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Пытаюсь написать игру "Пятнашки". В массиве у меня находится такая запись:

```
{ "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","_" }
```

Простое перемешивание может привести к тому, что комбинация - не будет иметь решения. Как правильно перемешивать, чтобы таких ситуаций не случалось?

Моя попытка кода:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a[16]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,15,14,0};//нерешаемая ситуация
    int inv=0;
    for(int i=0; i<16; ++i)
        if(a[i])
            for(int j=0; j<i; ++j)
                if(a[j]>a[i])
                    ++inv;
    for(int i=0; i<16; ++i)
        if(a[i]==0)
            inv += 1 + (i/4);
    puts((inv & 1) ? "NoSol" : "SolEx");
    return 0;
}
```

Первый цикл вычисляет количество инверсий. Второй цикл вычисляет где, находится пустая клетка.

Comment: Чтобы не мучиться с тем, что такое инверсии и как их считать, просто сложите их на поле правильно, и погоняйте пустую клетку случайным образом — несколько сотен раз должно хватить за глаза...

Comment: Не совсем понял, что значит погонять пустую клетку и что нужно сложить? Можете чуть-чуть детальнее объяснить?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZthXsFcFLo

Comment: *Как как правильно перемешивать, чтобы таких ситуаций не случалось?* Просто проверяй, что позиция решаема (количество превышений чётно). Если нет - меняй местами две последние кости.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос и покажите код который вы написали для решения задачи. (Указав нужный язык в тегах соответственно). Иначе этот вопрос могут закрыть, поскольку вопросы с решением задач должны содержать попытку решения в виде кода.

Comment: @Bloody.cpp это в первую очередь касается только учебных задач. А для решения этой задачи достаточно почитать Википедию.

Comment: Вставил свою попытку кода, но он не работает.

Comment: Что это? `for(int i;` ?

Comment: Ошибся, код слегка сюда переделанный вставлял, пропустил...

Comment: Я о том, что все равно у вас игровой массив двумерный будет, вот и расставляете как положено, а потом имитируете игру "наоборот" - случайным образом меняете пустое место с одной из соседних костей. И так несколько сотен раз.

Comment: После исправления цикла всё должно работать. Проверьте ещё раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как правильно написал @Harry - один из вариантов погонять случайным образом пустую клетку. Для наглядности можно использовать не одномерный массив, а двумерный - поле пятнашек 4x4. Начальное состояние:

```
int a[4][4] = {
{ 1, 2, 3, 4},
{ 5, 6, 7, 8},
{ 9,10,11,12},
{13,14,15, 0} };
```

Теперь датчиком случайных чисел выбираете направление и двигаете ноль. Например вверх - меняете 0 и 12 местами. Потом влево и ещё раз влево. Получается:

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4},     { 1, 2, 3, 4},     { 1, 2, 3, 4},
{ 5, 6, 7, 8}, =>  { 5, 6, 7, 8}, =>  { 5, 6, 7, 8},
{ 9,10,11, 0},     { 9,10, 0,11},     { 9, 0,10,11},
{13,14,15,12}      {13,14,15,12}      {13,14,15,12}
```

И так сотню раз. Поскольку ходы все корректные, результат тоже корректный.

Comment: Не хватает двух вещей - что сотни ходов достаточно и что распределение полученных позиций будет в каком-то смысле равномерном.

Comment: Восьмидесяти шагов достаточно для получения любой позиции. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B2_15#4_%C3%97_4

Comment: Я думаю достаточное количество ходов можно просто подобрать. Равномерное распределение - такого условия в задаче нет. :) 80 так 80.

Comment: Если совсем без равномерности, то будет как в анекдоте про генератор случайных чисел: "4, 4, 4, 4, ..." - "Ваш генератор не выглядит случайным!" - "В том и беда что вы никогда не знаете в порядке генератор или нет.".

Comment: :) так и есть - всё завязано на генератор случайных чисел. Ну есть математические методы по улучшению распределения данных генератора случайных чисел. Но это уже не из этого вопроса. Да и заморачиваться этим ради перемешивания фишек в игре "пятнашки"? Думаю для этой задачи достаточно стандартной выдачи `rand()`.